# How to use AWS CLI to only copy files in S3 bucket that match a given string pattern

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using the AWS CLI to copy files from an S3 bucket to my R machine using a command like below:

```
  system(
    "aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket_location/ ~/my_r_location/ --recursive --exclude '*' --include '*trans*' --region us-east-1"
    )
```

This works as expected, i.e. it copies all files in my_bucket_location that have "trans" in the filename at that location.

The problem that I am facing is that I have other files with similar naming conventions that I don't want to import in this step. As an example, in the list below I only want to copy the first two files, not the last two:

```
File list
trans_120215.csv
trans_130215.csv
sum_trans_120215.csv
sum_trans_130215.csv
```

If I was using regex I could make it more specific like `"^trans_\\d+"` to bring in just the first two files, but this doesn't seem possible using AWS CLI. So my question is there a way to have more complex pattern matching using AWS CLI like below?

```
  system(
    "aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket_location/ ~/my_r_location/ --recursive --exclude '*' --include '^trans_\\d+' --region us-east-1"
    )
```

Please note that I can only use information about the file in question, i.e. that I want to import a file with pattern `"^trans_\\d+"`, I can't use the fact that the other unwanted files contain sum_ at the start, because this is only an example there could be other files with similar names like "check_trans_120215.csv".

I have considered other alternatives like below, but hoping there is a way to adjust the copy command to avoid going down either of these routes:

- Listing all items in the bucket > using regex in R to specify the files that I want > Only importing those files
- Keeping the copy command as it is > delete unwanted files on the R machine after the copy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The alternatives that you have listed are the best options because S3 CLI doesn't support `regex`.

[Use of Exclude and Include Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters):

> Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in
>   a command's path arguments. However, most commands have --exclude
>   "" and --include "" parameters that can achieve the
>   desired result. These parameters perform pattern matching to either
>   exclude or include a particular file or object. The following pattern
>   symbols are supported.

```
*: Matches everything
?: Matches any single character
[sequence]: Matches any character in sequence
[!sequence]: Matches any character not in sequence
```

Answer (score 5):

Putting this here for others to find, since I just had to figure this out. Here's what I came up with:

```
s3cmd del $(s3cmd ls s3://[BUCKET]/ | grep '.*s3://[BUCKET]/[FILENAME]' | cut -c 41-)
```

You can put the regex in the grep search string. For instance, I was searching for specific files to delete (hence the s3cmd del). My regex looked like: `'2016-11-04.*s3.*[DN][RS].*'`. You may have to adjust the cut for your use. Should also work with `s3cmd get`.