# aws s3 cp download files to local of matching file name

Tags: amazon-s3, cp

I am trying to **download some images from amazon s3 bucket** with name like `126782129_06_12_2013.jpg`. I have tried using:

```
aws s3 cp s3://[s3 folder] [local folder] --exclude "*" --include "*_*.jpg"--recursive
```

But it gives not output.

Can someone help me with this?

**Edit:**

Some files are named as **1525780172306_bs516Z2.jpg** but I want to **ignore such files any only get the files containing digits after the '_' sign**.

Answer (score 0):

Aws cp doesnot support regex.
[documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

I downloaded all files and deleted unwanted files.

There should be better alternaties.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215713/how-to-use-aws-cli-to-only-copy-files-in-s3-bucket-that-match-a-given-string-pat too