# How to copy multiple files matching name pattern to AWS S3 bucket using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I would like to copy files matching a file name pattern from my machine to an AWS S3 bucket using [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html).  Using the standard [unix file name wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) does not work:

```
$ aws s3 cp *.csv s3://wesam-data/

Unknown options: file1.csv,file2.csv,file3.csv,s3://wesam-data/
```

I followed [this SO answer addressing a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222146/1181911) that advises using the `--exclude` and `--include` filters [as explained here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) as shown below without success.

```
$ aws s3 cp . s3://wesam-data/ --exclude "*" --include "*.csv"
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `aws s3 cp` does not work the same way as Linux/Mac `cp` where you can happily do `cp filea fileb filec somefolder/`.

Answer (score 8):

## Solution

```
$ aws s3 cp . s3://wesam-data/ --exclude "*" --include "*.csv" --recursive
```

## Explanation

It turns out that I have to use the [`--recursive` flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#single-local-file-and-s3-object-operations) with the `--include` & `--exclude` flags since this is a multi-file operation.

> The following commands are single file/object operations if no --recursive flag is provided.
>
> > - cp
> > - mv
> > - rm