# Java and S3 - It is possible to download files from the s3 bucket where the file name contains a specific value

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have some images in an s3 bucket where the filenames follow the format.

- Photo_1_**{cod_product}**.JPG  - ***ex: Photo_1_20215.JPG***
- Photo_2_**{cod_product}**.JPG  - ***ex: Photo_2_20215.JPG***
- Photo_3_**{cod_product}**.JPG  - ***ex: Photo_3_20215.JPG***

In other words, in the example, I have 3 images of the same product, and I would like to download the 3 images at once in order not to download 3

I would like to download the files using a snippet of the filename.

**Ex:** Download all files with product code **20215**

I found no reference on this possibility.

I'm using **Java (11)** with **Spring Boot (2.6.0)** and **aws-java-sdk version (1.11.1000)**

Comment: Check out [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215713/how-to-use-aws-cli-to-only-copy-files-in-s3-bucket-that-match-a-given-string-pat

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I verified that the example presented is using AWS CLI instructions, would the AWS SDK Java have the same capability?

Comment: No, download all 3 individually.